# Mule ESB dynamic http proxy

Tags: mule, esb

I am studying about MULE ESB. I would like to create an API Manager using ruby on rails and would like to know if there is any way to mapping my end-points in MULE dynamically. I mean, considering a user adding a new endpoint in my app, I would like to register that in my http proxy on MULE.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a great use case for the Dynamic Flows module:

- Introduced here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/adding-flows-dynamically/
- Available here: http://www.mulesoft.org/extensions/dynamic-flows

Answer (score 0):

You can see your answered with link below: http://www.ivankrizsan.se/2014/03/09/dynamic-http-proxy-with-mule/
https://dzone.com/articles/how-create-dynamic-http-proxy

Comment: While the link you provided may answer the question, it is best to put the essential parts of the solution directly in your answer in case the page at the link disappears in the future.